# Is taylor series also an orthogonal projection of a infinitely differentiable function on some subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion, orthonormal

I'm wondering if there exists some inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ defined on all real infinitely differentiable functions such that
$$1, x, x^2, x^3, \ldots$$
are orthonormal w.r.t this inner product?

If there does exist such an inner product, denote
$$U_j=\text{span}(1,x,\ldots,x^j).$$
Then, is it true that, for an arbitrary infinitely differentiable function $f$, $P_{U_j}(f)$ is $f$'s $j$th order taylor expansion at $x=0$?

Comment: Infinitely differentiable on the reals?

Comment: As far as existing goes, there are several, in the sense that any linearly independent sequence can be extended to a Hamel basis, and any basis is orthonormal in some product. You can also guarantee the existence of an inner product such that the projections don't do the thing you want.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio But Hamel Basis is not what we are looking for, is it?

Comment: @Filippo I don't know about you. I'm not looking for anything, I'm just reading the question.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Okay, I thought that the OP wants to interpret the taylor expansion as the representation of a function w.r.t. a Schauder basis.

Comment: @Filippo Make it pre-Hilbert basis, since he wants an inner product, which raises a question of normability (and pre-Hilbertability) of the topology of interest.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes. The question was posted because I see that Fourier series is an orthogonal projection so I wonder if taylor series is as well.

Comment: Possibly helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials, though not for infinitely differentiable functions, but in $L_2$.

Comment: Gabor Szego - Orthogonal polynomials - (4ed) on page 25 there is chapter orthogonal polynomials with exact answer with respect to non-negative powers of $x$.

Comment: @zkutch Yea I know about Legendre polynomials. But I'm looking for an inner product that actually makes $\{x^j\}$ into an orthonormal basis instead of a procedure that use it to produce an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to be explicit about an inner product making the monomials orthonormal:

> > **Lemma.** If $(c_n)$ is a sequence of complex numbers with $\sum|c_n|^2<\infty$ then the power series $\sum c_nx^n$ has radius of convergence at least $1$.

Proof: Suppose $|x|<1$. Then $\sum(|x|^n)^2<\infty$, hence $\sum c_nx^n$ converges, by Cauchy-Schwarz.

So we can let $H$ be the space of power series $\sum c_nx^n$ with $\sum|c_n|^2<\infty$ and define $$\left\langle\sum c_nx^n,\sum b_nx^n\right\rangle=\sum c_n\overline{b_n}.$$

And now it follows that the orthogonal projection onto the span of the first $n$ monomials is given by the $n$th partial sum.

Comment: What I was looking for is actually something like $$\langle f, x^n \rangle = \frac{d^nf}{dx^n} \bigg |_{x=0}.$$

Comment: @RyanHu That's clear from the definition of the inner product (if you insert the $n!$ in the right place...)

Answer (score 1):

If instead we considered *complex* differentiable functions, we could define an inner product by integrating over the unit circle:

$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^1 f(e^{2\pi it}) \overline{g(e^{2\pi it})}dt.$$

Then the desired identity

$$\langle f,x^n\rangle=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$$

follows from [Cauchy's differentiation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula). In particular, the monomials are orthonormal.

You can express the key idea here as a commutative diagram: Taking the Taylor series and then restricting to the unit circle is equivalent to restricting to the unit circle and then taking the Fourier series.

Comment: This is very helpful! thank you.